# Next/Previous navigation through predefined list of HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Im in a bit of a pickle here, I've bin googleing for some time now, but cant seem to find what Im looking for, so i hope you guys can help.

I want to create a list/array of unique URL´s, that i can navigate through with Next/Previous buttons.

Something like this:

```
var caseList = [
    'case-name-of-some-client.html',
    'case-another-client-name.html',
    'case-one-more-client-name.html',
    'case-last-client-name.html'
];
<a href="#" onClick="caseListGotoNextUrl">Next</a>
<a href="#" onClick="caseListGotoPreviousUrl">Previous</a>
```

Example: i am on www.mydomain.com/case-another-client-name.html, and click next, it checks the url in the address bar, and takes me to www.mydomain.com/case-one-more-client-name.html, because its next on the list, and vice versa if i click Previous.

It would also be nice, if it could loop, so when its at the end of the list, i just goes to the first url again, and vice versa.

Im a total noob with all this js stuff, so any help would be appreciated.

Cheers, Jens

p.s. i am using jquery.

Comment: Have you written more code than what you have here?

Comment: Nope. I have no idea where i would start. I know its a lousy question, seeing that i cant provide any more code, sorry.

Comment: I'd recommend doing some JavaScript tutorials, so that you can get more familiar with the concepts involved.  Some other questions:  Are you going to a client page as a new request, or are you using jQuery to load in the html into an element on your page?  This would affect the solution needed.

Comment: Im not loading any content in to the page, i would like the URL to change frome domainname.com/01.html to domainname.com/02.html. And thanks for the advice, i´m on it (code academy) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place these codes on every page in your list (you can simple include jquery part on every page):

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="next">Next</a>
<a href="" class="prev">Previous</a>
```

JQuery:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var caseList = [
    'case-name-of-some-client.html',
    'case-another-client-name.html',
    'case-one-more-client-name.html',
    'case-last-client-name.html'
];

    current=$(location).attr('pathname').substr($(location).attr('pathname').lastIndexOf("/")+1); // get current page: just last part - page name and extension
    if($.inArray(current, caseList)!==-1) { //check if it is in array
        index=$.inArray(current, caseList);
    }
    //navigate thorough pages...
    $( ".next" ).click(function() {
    if(index<caseList.length){
    next=caseList[index+1];
    window.location.href = next;
    }
    });

    $( ".prev" ).click(function() {
    if(index>=0){
    prev=caseList[index-1];
    window.location.href = prev;
    }
    });

    });
```

Comment: PERFECT, that was exactly what i was looking for :) Thanks a million. One last thing. Is it posible to loop this? so when you hit next on the last page, it goes to the first page on the list, and vice versa, when you are on the first page and click prev.?

Comment: Hi, no problem. About loop: yes. Few conditions more - try by yourself... shouldn't be too hard. If you fail - i will help later. :)

Comment: i set this as the right answer, seeing how it put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var caseList = [
    'case-name-of-some-client.html',
    'case-another-client-name.html',
    'case-one-more-client-name.html',
    'case-last-client-name.html'
];
var iCount=0;
function caseListGotoNextUrl(){
  iCount++;
  if(iCount === 3) iCount=0;
  $(this).attr('href', caseList[iCount]); 
}

function caseListGotoPreviousUrl(){
 iCount--;
 if(iCount<0) iCount=3;
 $(this).attr('href', caseList[iCount]); 
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using caseList.length-1, instead of a hard-coded 3.  It's more flexible and requires less maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would i go about implementing this? Once again, i am sorry for my stupidity!

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from my friends :) we came up with this

```
/** Next/prev case **/
var caseList = [
    'case-bang-and-olufsen.html',
    'case-bang-and-olufsen-02.html',
    'case-bang-and-olufsen-03.html'
];



current=$(location).attr('pathname').substr($(location).attr('pathname').lastIndexOf("/")+1); // get current page: just last part - page name and extension
if($.inArray(current, caseList)!==-1) { //check if it is in array
    index=$.inArray(current, caseList);
}

$(".arrow-right").click(function(){

    var CSL = caseList.length; //CaselistArray length - 1
    var CC = 0; //CurrentCASE

    CC  = index;
    next  = caseList[CC +1];

        if(CC < CSL-1){
            next = caseList[CC +1];
            window.location.href = next;
        }
        else{
            next = caseList[0];
            window.location.href = next;
        }
});

$(".arrow-left").click(function(){

    var CSL = caseList.length; //CaselistArray length - 1
    var CC = 0; //CurrentCASE

    CC  = index;
    prev  = caseList[CC -1];

    if(CC > 0){
        prev = caseList[CC -1];
        window.location.href = prev;
    }
    else{
        prev = caseList[CSL-1];
        window.location.href = prev;
    }
});
```